# I'm going to have a mental breakdown. My query outputs the same result several times

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, where-clause

If i block a user my status is output more than once. Nobody else's, just mine.

If I block 3 users, my status update appears 3 times (the same status repeats).
If I block 10 users, my status repeats 10 times.

This must be that bloody WHERE clause again... right?

```
//Get status results
        $sql = "SELECT 

        tbl_status.id as statID, 
        tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
        tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
        tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
        tbl_status.date as statDATE,

        tbl_users.id as usrID, 
        tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
        tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
        tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

        tbl_blocking.id as blockID,
        tbl_blocking.user as blockUSER,
        tbl_blocking.blocking as blockBLOCKING,
        tbl_blocking.date as blockDATE,
        tbl_blocking.block_by as blockBY,
        tbl_blocking.active as blockACTIVE

        FROM tbl_status 

        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking.blocking

        WHERE 
        tbl_status.deleted = '0'
        AND tbl_blocking.user != :who
        OR tbl_blocking.user IS NULL

        ORDER BY 
        tbl_status.date desc

        LIMIT 200

        ";
```

Comment: quick fix might be select distinct (if your rdbms allows for it)? IF that doesn't fix can you post the returned data so that we can identify what is causing the duplication.

Comment: The question should be self-contained this one isn't. Plus it has to much noise. Rash language won't help get a quicker response nor will telling in the title that you're going to get a mental breakdown. The more your panic the worst it gets. Relax take a deep breadth it's not the end of the world. And clean-up the question please.

Comment: 4th Question on same query. Looks like an [**xy problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE-condition mixes AND and OR, there's a precedence of evaluation, NOT - AND - OR

This is your current condition, adding brackets for clarity:

```
WHERE 
     (tbl_status.deleted = '0' AND tbl_blocking.user != :who)
  OR tbl_blocking.user IS NULL
```

You might want this intead:

```
WHERE 
      tbl_status.deleted = '0'
  AND (tbl_blocking.user != :who OR tbl_blocking.user IS NULL)
```